# How to add an underscore mixin library to WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, underscore.js, webstorm

In my work, we have a file with utilities functions that are extended in `_.mixin()` function at runtime. No, I cannot change the framework, because  the solution would be to separate those function from `_.mixin()` and make them and indepent module, that would be the best.

Either way, my problem is that I cannot link this file, with all the extended functions in WebStorm, so I always see `Unresolved function or method warning`

Yes I have tried to add the file in the **Library tab** under *Libraries & Framework* preferences. And it did nothing.

So my question is, It is possible to WebStorm (or other Atlassian software) to link a file with several functions that will be extended with Underscore.js `_.mixin() function` to show up in Autocomplete?

Thanks, in advance

Comment: adding the file to libraries won't help here. `_.mixin()` dynamically adds passed utility functions to `_` object, it's not possible to resolve such dynamically generated stuff during static code analysis unless a special treatment for the certain functions is provided. And WebStorm doesn't provide any special support for `_.mixin()` function.

Comment: Thanks @lena I thought so. It would be very neat to have this possibility,

If you answer the question, I will mark it as solved, :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the file to JavaScript libraries won't help here. `_.mixin()` dynamically adds passed utility functions to `_` object, it's not possible to resolve such dynamically generated stuff during static code analysis unless a special treatment for the certain functions is provided. And WebStorm doesn't provide any special support for `_.mixin()`.
If you miss it, please feel free to create a feature request in youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB